What does unifirm weave mean?
**What does unifirm weave mean?

It might be a typo: uniform weave, or it might be a poor translation of say "loose weave".

Please always provide a source text.

Re my first comment and the edit: originally unfirm.

Yup, a uniform weave would have an even texture like a cotton sheet or dress shirt.
